# disable <button> with jQuery Mobile causes frame

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button, frame

i am using jquery 2.0 with jquery mobile 1.4.

if i disable a  there is a Frame around the Button. It's still there if i enable the button again.

```
$("#speichern").button({disabled:true});
```

button tag:

```
<button id="artSave" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-all ui-btn-b"> speichern</button>
```

i don't like to use an anchor, because it can't disable the button fully.
i also had some drawbacks with

[picture of frame around the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRyZu.png)

thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle?

Comment: `#speichern` there isn't any button with that `id`. Your button id is `artSave` probably a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable a `button` or `a` tags, add class `ui-state-disabled`. Use [`.button()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/) widget only with `input` that has `type` *button*, *submit* or *reset*.

When you use `.button()` on any element other than `input`, you convert it into an `input` button and hence you get a wrapper around it.

- Disable/Enable an `input` button:

  ```
  $(".selector").button("disable");
  $(".selector").button("enable");
  ```
- Disable/Enable `button` tag:

  ```
  $(".selector").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
  $(".selector").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
  ```
- Disable/Enable `a` anchor tag:

  ```
  $(".selector").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
  $(".selector").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/upQUB/)**