# how to remove the wrapper div around a button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I recently upgraded my project from jQuery mobile 1.0 to 1.4.2. In my old code, I had a button with my own custom class.

`<button class="set-date" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-r">Set Date</button>`

After I upgraded to latest jQuery mobile, this didn't work. I changed the code as,

```
<button class="set-date ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-a">Set Date</button>
```

The javascript for this button is:

```
$(".set-date",page).click(function(event){      
    event.preventDefault();

    $.mobile.loader('show');
    $.mobile.changePage("set-date");
    ...
});
```

But, this makes the button inside another button. When I inspect element, I saw a wrapper div around the button.

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
<button class="set-date ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-last-child">Set Date</button>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how could I remove this wrapper div?

Comment: use `a` anchor instead of `button`, that's all.

Comment: same result with anchor as well.

Comment: are you using `.button()` function?

Comment: yes, since anchor is also a button I use .button() function

Comment: is there another way to enable and disable that button without using `.button()` function?

Comment: dont use `.button()` on anchors nor on `button`. use it for `input type=button` only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable <button> with jQuery Mobile causes frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726283/disable-button-with-jquery-mobile-causes-frame)

Answer (score 1):

use `.unwrap()`:

```
$('button.set-date').unwrap();
```

Comment: create a fiddle and check yourself.

Comment: this isn't jQuery-Mobile.

Comment: **1)** [jQuery-Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is a framework **2)** jsfiddle works on mobiles and tablets.