# Extra container appearing around button in jQuery Mobile 1.4.2

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I have a `<button>` in jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 that's being shown with an extra `<div>` container appearing around it. I did not have this problem with jQM 1.3.2.

This is the code I'm using (*note that the problem doesn't appear in jsFiddle*):

```html
<div data-theme="a" data-role="page">    
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <button id="test1" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" title="test1">Test 1</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the fiddle that shows the extra div inserted by jQM: [Demo With Extra Div](http://jsfiddle.net/hkbTq/)

How do I get rid of the extra div?

Comment: are you using `.button()` on the `<button>`?

Comment: Ah yes, that's what's causing the extra div. I guess I will have to attach the click event differently for the mobile version. If you create an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery Mobile 1.4, use `.button()` only for `input` with type `button`, `submit` or `reset`.

`input` is converted into a div that holds all styles.

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
  Submit
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

If you call `.button()` on `<a>` or `<button>` tags, they will be wrapped in a div.

Comment: Thanks @Omar, how to replace `$('#buttonID').button('enable');` in JQM 1.4 ?

Comment: I mean on `<a>` or `<button>` tags.

Comment: @Louis `#(".selector").addClass("ui-state-disabled");` http://stackoverflow.com/a/21726607/1771795